# Replace start or end of string in values of pandas column with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

With sed, I can do

```
$ sed 's/^/prefix/' <<EOF
> foo
> EOF
prefixfoo
```

When I use [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), the regex does **not** work. The minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["foo", "bar"]})
df.text.str.replace("^", "prefix", regex=True)
```

returns

```
0    foo
1    bar
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you capture the `^`:

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(^)', 'prefix', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    prefixfoo
1    prefixbar
Name: text, dtype: object
```

That said the best method to prepend a string would be to concatenate:

```
'prefix'+df['text']
```

Comment: `regex=True` is the default behavior of `str.replace` and we usually don't write it explicitly.

Comment: @Tim which pandas version are you using? This will change to False in a future release and currently raises a warning if you don't explicitly pass True

Comment: "*FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.*"